# How to use a module to specify multiple components in Angular 6

Tags: angular

I want to use module joke.module.ts to specify multiple components; in this case I start with JokeComponent in joke/joke.module.ts in src/app

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';/
@Component({
  selector: 'joke',
  template: `
  <h1>What did the cheese say when it looked in the mirror?</h1>
  <p>Halloumi (hello me)</p>  `
})

export class JokeComponent {
}
```

In app.component.ts I want to use joke/joke.module.ts and use the tag 'joke'

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { JokeModule } from './joke/joke.module';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
  <joke></joke>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
}
```

I have create module joke.module.ts in src/app/joke

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { JokeComponent } from './joke.component';
import { AppComponent } from '../app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ AppComponent ],
  declarations: [
    JokeComponent
  ],
  entryComponents: [JokeComponent]
})
export class JokeModule { }
```

However, when I run the application I am getting the error
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
'joke' is not a known element:
1. If 'joke' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.

Comment: you'll need to import the JokeModule into your AppModule

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/feature-modules

Answer (score 2):

Your imports and declarations seems to be wrong. Correct them like this :

1. Import `JokeModule` inside your `AppModule`.
2. Remove `entryComponents: [JokeComponent]` from `JokeModule`, instead add it in `AppModule` as `entryComponents: [AppComponent]`.
3. Remove `imports:[ AppComponent ]` from `JokeModule`
4. export `JokeComponent` in `JokeModule`as  `exports : [JokeComponent]`

Your bootsrtap component should be `AppComponent`, rest of the components will be a child components to your `app-root` component.

Working [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ldhxm4)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer. The main problem is that the code I presented was wrong. Initially I have a simple application created with Angular/cli.
joke.component.ts in src/app/jokes (I want a separate folder for the functionality)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'joke',
  template: `
  <h1>What did the cheese say when it looked in the mirror?</h1>
  <p>Halloumi (hello me)</p>  `
})

export class JokeComponent {
```

I use tag 'joke' in app.component.ts as follows

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
  <joke></joke>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
}

I am not importing joke.component.ts because I have imported and declared it in app.module.ts
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
//import { JokeModule } from './jokes/joke.module';
import { JokeComponent } from './jokes/joke.component';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent, JokeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

What I am seeing is that anything imported and declared in app.module.ts is available to other components (In this case app.component). 
For a large program with multiple functionality, I want to create components for different functionalities in separate folders. What I don't want is to import every component in app.module.ts; For every functionality I want to create a module like joke.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { JokeComponent } from './joke.component';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    JokeComponent
  ],
  exports: [JokeComponent]
})

export class JokeModule { }
```

In this module I import and declare the components for the functionality and I was hoping that importing and declaring these modules in app.module.ts would work, but It didn't.

Comment: If you check the code properly, which I have presented in my DEMO, it does not import `JokeComponent` inside `AppModule`. It is simply importing `JokeModule`. The main problem behind the `JokeComponent` not accessible inside your `AppModule` is that you have not exported `JokeComponent` inside `JokeModule`. Check step no 4.